# How I can compare these two .json files correctly using jq in a bash script

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a bash script that is set up below which is attempting to compare the remote s3 version of a file with the local version. Currently, the if conditions I try never actually work. The latest version is below, I am simply looking to create a temp s3 file and initialize it with the s3 version, compare the temp s3 with the local, if there are differences than I want to have the temp s3 file get the latest updates and then after the s3 file is updated to remove the temp files. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as this below setup always results in the code not detecting any differences, even when I manually create differences to test the logic.

Current setup:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

FILE_NAME = config.json
REMOTE_FILE_LOCATION="s3://path/to/s3/file/$FILE_NAME"

aws cp $REMOTE_FILE_LOCATION s3-$FILE_NAME

if ! jq -s '.[0] == .[1]' "$FILE_NAME" "s3-$FILE_NAME" &> /dev/null; then
     echo "differences found"

     cp $FILE_NAME s3-$FILE_NAME

     aws s3 cp s3-$FILE_NAME $REMOTE_FILE_LOCATION
 else
     echo "No differences - local and s3 files in sync."
fi

rm -r $s3-$FILE_NAME
```

Tried re-writing the if conditions, actually building logic to compare objects in each files based on their id, yet I have not been able to get the if condition to correctly determine when .json files are the same vs. when they are not. Previous solutions resolving around comparing JSON files did not have an answer where there was a solution that worked with jq. I have tried multiple suggestions from prior posts.

Comment: Could you make a [mcve] including sample json files? Is this about the aws up/downloading or the json comparison? Whatever it is, leave the other part out. Also, what happens when you run your code and what did you expect to happen instead? Have you tried something like `diff <(jq --sort-keys . A.json) <(jq --sort-keys . B.json)` to compare JSON documents?

Comment: `.[0] == .[1]` just produces a string (`true` or `false`). This does not affect the exit code. You might want to use jq's `--exit-status` (or `-e`) option.